# predicate from js to objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-ui-testing

I had a .js file for my screenshot automation with Instruments.app where I was looking up a cell with the following predicate:

```
var classScheduleCell = classScheduleTableView.cells().firstWithPredicate("isEnabled == 1 && NONE staticTexts.value BEGINSWITH 'No classes'").withValueForKey(1, "isVisible");
```

I want to translate that predicate to an objective C UI test, as the ruby scripts I was using for the screenshots now uses UI testing instead of Instruments. Using the same predicate fails

```
XCUIElement *firstCell = [classScheduleTableView.cells elementMatchingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isEnabled == 1 && NONE staticTexts.value BEGINSWITH 'No classes'"]];
```

Looks like I can make the first part of the predicate work changing

```
isEnabled == 1
```

for

```
enabled == true
```

Any ideas on how to make the other part work?

Comment: If you separate the predicate in two, you may point out what part of the (&& case) doesn't work? I don't use `XCUIElement`, but `staticTexts.text` I don't know what are `staticTexts`?

Comment: If I sepparate it in two, I can make the first part work changing isEnabled == 1 for enabled == true.
staticTexts.value was the predicate to find label values in .js using Instruments.app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this, though is not the most elegant. I couldn't find a way to make a predicate to work as the one I had in UI Automation, so I used a couple of for loops to check the value of the cell labels.

```
NSPredicate *enabledCellsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"enabled == true "];
XCUIElementQuery *enabledCellsQuery = [classScheduleTableView.cells matchingPredicate:enabledCellsPredicate];
int cellCount = enabledCellsQuery.count;
for (int i = 0; i < cellCount; i++) {
    XCUIElement *cellElement = [enabledCellsQuery elementBoundByIndex:i];
    XCUIElementQuery *cellStaticTextsQuery = cellElement.staticTexts;
    int textCount = cellStaticTextsQuery.count;
    BOOL foundNoClasses = NO;
    for (int j = 0; j < textCount; j++) {
        XCUIElement *textElement = [cellStaticTextsQuery elementBoundByIndex:j];
        if (textElement.value && [textElement.value rangeOfString:NSLocalizedString(@"No classes", nil) options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
            foundNoClasses = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (foundNoClasses == NO) {
        [cellElement tap];
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks @joe-masilotti for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your exact predicate is possible with UI Testing.

### UI Testings vs UI Automation

Matching predicates with UI Testing (UIT) behaves a little differently than UI Automation (UIA) did. UIA had more access to the actual UIKit elements. UIT is a more black-box approach, only being able to interact with elements via the accessibility APIs.

### `NOT` Predicate

Breaking down your query I'm assuming the second part is trying to find the first cell *not* titled 'No classes'. First, let's just match `staticTexts`.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT label BEGINSWITH 'No classes'")
let firstCell = app.staticTexts.elementMatchingPredicate(predicate)
XCTAssert(firstCell.exists)
firstCell.tap() // UI Testing Failure: Multiple matches found
```

As noted in the comment, trying to tap the "first" cell raises an exception. This is because there is more than one match for a text label that starts with "No classes".

### `NONE` Predicate

Using the `NONE` operator of NSPredicate leads us down a different path.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NONE label BEGINSWITH 'No classes'")
let firstCell = app.staticTexts.elementMatchingPredicate(predicate)
XCTAssert(firstCell.exists)// XCTAssertTrue failed: throwing "The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet." -
```

This approach can't even find the cell. This is because the `elementMatchingPredicate()` expects the predict to return a single instance, not an array or set. I couldn't figure out how to make the query select the first element. And once you get an `XCUIElement` there are no ways to farther restrict it.

### Different Approach

That said I suggest you take a slightly different approach for your test. If your tests are deterministic, and they should be, just tap the first known cell. This means you don't have to worry about ambiguous matchers nor chaining predicates.

```
let firstCell = app.staticTexts["Biology"]
XCTAssert(firstCell.exists)
firstCell.tap()
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to find the first enabled cell that hasn't the "No classes" text in it. The cell contents are dynamic and vary often. I'll try again with your first predicate, but using `matchingPredicate` instead of `elementMatchingPredicate `, so if I get an `XCUIElementQuery` I can then get the first element with `elementBoundByIndex`. I'll let you know if this works